# Wordpress how to fetch records from database

Tags: php, database, wordpress, fetch, custom-wordpress-pages

I am fetching records from two tables at once.

- one is a questions table
- the other is an options table

Each question has many options, i'm running the below code but it echos nothing, no error, no result.

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-3">
<div class="questions">
<?php
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_dbquestions"); // Query to fetch data from database table and storing in $results
if(!empty($results))                        // Checking if $results have some values or not
{ 
    echo"<p>$results->text</p>";
     }
     $results1 = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_questoptions WHERE question_id=1"); // Query to fetch data from database table and storing in $results
if(!empty($results1)) { 
    foreach($results1 as $row){ 
   echo"<form class="options">";
        echo"<input class="option" type="radio">$row->text <br>";
        echo"<input class="option" type="hidden">$row->score <br>";
    echo"</form>";
   }
?>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how about doing print_r($results);  before if condition?

Comment: How you get value for this echo"<p>$row->text</p>"; before that there is no foreach!!

Comment: what's your `table` name???

Comment: i did print_r the question is okay

Comment: the first query is okay its working while the second is printing values on print_r but not when i run the whole thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While testing/debugging you can add this

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>
```

on top of your php file to see all errors.

If you want to use the Wordpress database you have to "declare $wpdb as a global variable using the global keyword, or use the superglobal $GLOBALS"

```
// 1st Method - Declaring $wpdb as global and using it to execute an SQL query statement that returns a PHP object

global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}options WHERE option_id = 1", OBJECT );

// 2nd Method - Utilizing the $GLOBALS superglobal. Does not require global keyword ( but may not be best practice )

$results = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}options WHERE option_id = 1", OBJECT );
```

From:

```
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb
```

Comment: global did it and a lill modification in input types thanks